# how to solve com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'task4DB.tst' doesn't exist exceptions

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm a student and I've tried to write this code in order to display the first name of employees which are stored in a database on "mysql" server  and I've got these exception although the table exist!! :

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'task4DB.tst' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3283)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1332)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1467)

how to solve these problems :( ??

```
public static void search() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException

{    
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/task4DB?"
              + "user=root&password=123");

   PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("select * from tst");

    ArrayList<String> fName = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> lName = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();


    ResultSet RS=st.executeQuery("select * from tst ");

      loop1:
    for(String s : fName )

    {

          while (RS.next()) {
fName.add(RS.getString("fName"));


    }

      for(int i=0;i<fName.size();i++ )

      {
          System.out.println(fName.get(i));

      }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well `createStatement` doesn't return a `PreparedStatment` - it returns a `Statement`. You need to pass the SQL to the `prepareStatement` method instead:

```
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("select * from tst");
```

Then:

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
```

While you *can* still call the overload of `executeQuery` which takes SQL, you generally shouldn't. (I think it was probably a mistake to make `PreparedStatement` extend `Statement`.)

Note that you should also close the connection, statement, and result set in finally blocks. Also, I've renamed your `RS` variable to follow Java naming conventions somewhat, although I'd probably just call it `results` or something similar.

Additionally, your loop is broken - `fName` is empty, so there's no point in looping over it. You probably want:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    fName.add(rs.getString("fName"));
}
```

Comment: Thank u I think this answer helpful but when I've altered the code, I've got these exceptions "see the post plz"

Comment: @Akari: Well the exception seems fairly self-explanatory to me - the table you're trying to query doesn't exist.

Comment: but it is already exist :( 
in task4DB and Ive filled this table using mysql workbench

Comment: @Akari: Well the exception says otherwise. Check the table name very carefully. There's not a lot we can do to help you with that.

Answer (score 4):

it should be `con.prepareStatement("THE_SQL_QUERY")`

Comment: something like this :
PreparedStatement st = con.PreparedStatement();

Comment: There's no parameterless overload for `prepareStatement` - the OP needs to supply the SQL to `prepareStatement`, and then *not* supply it when calling `executeQuery`. In other words, I don't think this answer is detailed enough to be helpful.

Comment: Even after the change, there's still a bunch more to be done before the OP's code would work. See my answer.

Comment: yep.. will try to elaborate next time :) I guess i dont need to edit my answer after your detailed one